# Why my PostgreSQL query is taking less time after one execution?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to execute a simple select query with some where condition from existing table which nearly about 3,00,000 records.
When I am executing it first time it is completing it in around 200 sec while second time it is taking around 20 seconds.

Comment: Because the second time the data is cached

Comment: Because many of the records are now already in your RAM/main memory and thus they do not need to be fetched again from the drive. This makes a huge difference, as disk accesses are usually the slowest part of the execution. This is also known as "caching".

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com (in this case, it actually works *for* us :P)

Comment: yes but Can we disable that caching for temporary use to test some queries? If yes then how to disable it (I don't allow to restart the postgres server.)